# Jquery file upload angular version - multiple file upload on the same page

Tags: angularjs, callback, jquery-file-upload

Cheers,

here is a good example how to use jquery-file-upload plugin with angularjs
[how to use jquery file upload angular version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782297/how-to-use-jquery-file-upload-angular-version)

BUT! What if on the same page we need few widgets?

```
<form class="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
<form class="fileupload" action="server/php/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <!-- ... -->
</form>
```

This example works good, except:

1. Callbacks. Using $scope.$on() is not quite right. How to specify specific callbacks for each widget?
2. Drag-n-Drop. Seems like drag-n-drop area is also shared between two widgets, so when I drop the file at any place on the page both events triggered. So again, how to specify drop areas for each one?

My though is that jquery-file-upload can cover all this requirements itself and its all about poor [jQuery File Upload AngularJS Plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload-angular.js)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how to fix this but [angular-file-upload directive](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) might save you the hassle.
It is lightweight and simple to use and it supports non-HTML5 browsers with FileAPI flash shim. It also supports drag&drop and upload progress.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="file" ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files)" multiple>
  <div class="drop-box" ng-file-drop="onFileSelect($files);" ng-show="ddSupported">drop files here</div>
  <div ng-file-drop-available="dropSupported=true" ng-show="!ddSupported">HTML5 Drop File is not suported></div>
```

JS:

```
//inject angular file upload directive.
angular.module('myApp', ['angularFileUpload']);

var MyCtrl = [ '$scope', '$upload', function($scope, $upload) {
  $scope.onFileSelect = function($files) {
    //$files: an array of files selected, each file has name, size, and type.
    for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
      var $file = $files[i];
      $upload.upload({
        url: 'my/upload/url',
        file: $file,
        progress: function(e){}
      }).then(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // file is uploaded successfully
        console.log(data);
      }); 
    }
  }
}];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had simmilar problems and was not able to find ANY exaple how to use more input fields at once, so I `toyed` with and after some quite **loooong** time experimenting with it, i finaly found a really easy solution:

- you just need separate controller for each of the input fields and in (for) each of those you need to specify its drop zone... for example like this:

  < form ng-controller="MyVideoUploadController">< div id="videoFilesInputZone" >< /div >< /form >

  < form ng-controller="MyAudioUploadController">< div id="audioFilesInputZone" >< /div >< /form >

  ```
  .controller('MyVideoUploadController', [
  '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
  function ($scope) {
      $scope.options = {
          dropZone: $("#videoFilesInputZone")
      };
      $scope.loadingFiles = true;
  }]).controller('MyAudioUploadController', [
  '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
  function ($scope) {
      $scope.options = {
          dropZone: $("#audioFilesInputZone")
      };
      $scope.loadingFiles = true;
  }
  ```

  ])

and thats all you need. 
Only drawback is that you can not drop the files just anywhere, but must drop them exactly over the selected elements...